# Azure Flask web app not working

Tags: python, azure, flask

I am trying to deploy my Azure web app using the Flask framework.  Whenever I deploy it, I get a server 500 error.  However, when I comment out

```
import pyodbc
```

it comes up fine.  Any ideas why using the pyodbc library is keeping my web app from working properly?

Also, how do I debug to find error codes to help troubleshoot this issue?
So far, I see the following on my log file:

> StdErr:  2017-08-18 23:12:02.085000: Unhandled exception in
>   wfastcgi.py: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
>       env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)   File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
>       return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)   File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler
>       handler = handler()   File ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 98, in get_virtualenv_handler
>       handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER'))   File
>   ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 85, in get_wsgi_handler
>       raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name) ValueError: "rsit_tools.app" could not be imported 2017-08-18
>   23:12:02.100000: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 closed 2017-08-18 23:19:53.953000:
>   wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 started 2017-08-18 23:19:53.969000: Python version:
>   2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] 2017-08-18 23:19:53.969000: wfastcgi.py 2.1.1 initializing 2017-08-18
>   23:19:54: Activating virtualenv with
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\activate_this.py 2017-08-18
>   23:19:54.031000: Getting handler rsit_tools.app 2017-08-18
>   23:19:55.316000: Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
>       env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)   File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
>       return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)   File "D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py", line 541, in get_wsgi_handler
>       handler = handler()   File ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 98, in get_virtualenv_handler
>       handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv('WSGI_ALT_VIRTUALENV_HANDLER'))   File
>   ".\ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py", line 85, in get_wsgi_handler
>       raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)
>   ValueError: "rsit_tools.app" could not be imported

Comment: Have you installed pyodbc in your virtual environment in azure?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a 64 bit virtual env. Azure is 32 bit. Once I covered to 32 bit, it worked great.